# How does an std::vector copy its data for reallocation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I wrote a template array class similar to std::vector except it reuses empty indices or 'holes' when an element is erased, instead of moving all the following elements back to fill it.

I ran into a bug though when I tried to store a nontrivial object as I was using memcpy to copy elements during reallocation. Does std::vector loop through all its elements and call the copy constructor, or does it use some other trick that I'm unaware of?

Comment: in C++11 the elements are move-constructed, before that they were copied

Comment: Why not crack open the source code and find out? It's right there in your directory of C++ headers. Of course it"s just one implementation, but it probably implements the standard correctly so studying it should be of some help. In general, if you could copy anything with `memcpy`, why would C++ have copy and move constructors?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, copying the elements then destroying the originals is the basic idea.

You can optimize with template metaprogramming, of course:

- If the type has a trivial copy constructor, you *can* use `memcpy`
- If the type has a trivial destructor, you can skip that step

C++11 adds a new dimension in that you can move the objects too.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not use memcpy() for non-pods. Classic vanilla C++03 implementation would be to use copy constructor, but this is not very productive. In C++11, you can use whole arsenal of meta-info, such as is_trivially_copyable to perform memcpy() when applicable, check for presence of move constructor, etc.